# PostgreSQL: Is it possible to determine if any elements in an array overlap a range?

Tags: sql, postgresql, range, postgresql-12

Let's say I have a table with an `int[]` column and values:

`'[1,4,1300]'::int4[]`

I want to be able to query the column and get a `true` if ANY of the elements match a `BETWEEN` statement. So, in this case, something like:

`SELECT id FROM table WHERE col && '[1000,2000]'::int4range` or similar.

The column uses `gist__int_ops`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dogmatic answer is that you shouldn't use arrays in your tables, and should use child tables instead.  I don't usually adhere to dogma, but in this case I think that this is probably the pragmatic answer, as well.  I don't see anything in the extensibility API for indexes that looks like you could even implement your own extension to do this.

If you use a child table, you would go back to using `BETWEEN..AND` for your query, rather than int4range, to obtain indexability.

Comment: Good ol' EAV still going strong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a range with the [containment operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html), e.g.:

```
select id 
from my_table 
where '[2,4]'::int4range @> any(col)
```

Unfortunately, the query does not use the index. I do not think you can find a query that does it (without defining your own operator).

Update. You can try to convert the range to an array.

```
create or replace function int_range_to_array(int4range)
returns int[] language sql immutable as $$
    select array(
        select i 
        from generate_series(lower($1), upper($1)- 1) i)
$$;

select id
from my_table 
where col && int_range_to_array('[2,4]');
```

Obviously, the performance depends on range sizes.

Comment: Yeah, it's the not using the index part that kills. Although I have written C functions for PG, I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: I think it's possible but the subject is too broad for this site.

Comment: I think it's perhaps too specialized for this site.

Comment: Of course, too specialized. I used the phrase commonly used here describing similar issues.

Comment: I understand. The phrase is ironic. It occurred to me that I might just have to use the EAV model approach to solve this. I suppose that's not such a terrible approach. Interestingly, the only storage engine I've found that is capable of this type of query is ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can `unnest()`:

```
where exists (select 1
              from unnest(col) u(val)
              where u.val between 2 and 4
             )
```

Comment: I don't believe that will use the index, though.